# No nodes in Hadoop setup

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup 2 nodes in my Hadoop "cluster" in VirtualBox. In the master node, I have setup

The master slaves config:

```
hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ cat slaves 
Master
Slave
```

Slave's hosts file

```
hadoop@Slave:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.56.102  Master
127.0.0.1 Slave
```

Slave's  `core-site.xml`

```
hadoop@Slave:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ cat core-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/tmp</value>
<description>Abase for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>fs.defaultFS</name>
<value>hdfs://Slave:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

In master I have run:

```
hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh 
18/03/18 12:46:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-Master.out
Slave: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-Slave.out
Master: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-Master.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-Master.out
18/03/18 12:46:41 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable


hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-yarn.sh 
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-Master.out
Slave: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-Slave.out
Master: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-Master.out


hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
starting historyserver, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/mapred-hadoop-historyserver-Master.out
```

Seems like no issues here? Then I go `http://localhost:8088/cluster/nodes`

[image]

But there is no nodes, why is this? Is there any other config I should post here?

---

**Update: Checking out my logs ...**

It seems like there maybe some issues starting my nodes?

```
hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ tail -n 100 /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-Master.out
ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 11659
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 11659
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ tail -n 100 /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-Master.out
ulimit -a for user hadoop
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 11659
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 11659
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**Update 2: Resource manager logs**

```
2018-03-18 16:13:29,464 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: default: capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>, usedCapacity=0.0, absoluteUsedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2018-03-18 16:13:29,464 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue: root: numChildQueue= 1, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2018-03-18 16:13:29,464 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized root queue root: numChildQueue= 1, capacity=1.0, absoluteCapacity=1.0, usedResources=<memory:0, vCores:0>usedCapacity=0.0, numApps=0, numContainers=0
2018-03-18 16:13:29,464 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized queue mappings, override: false
2018-03-18 16:13:29,465 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: Initialized CapacityScheduler with calculator=class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator, minimumAllocation=<<memory:1024, vCores:1>>, maximumAllocation=<<memory:8192, vCores:4>>, asynchronousScheduling=false, asyncScheduleInterval=5ms
2018-03-18 16:13:29,497 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.metrics.SystemMetricsPublisher: YARN system metrics publishing service is not enabled
2018-03-18 16:13:29,498 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioning to active state
2018-03-18 16:13:29,653 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Updating AMRMToken
2018-03-18 16:13:29,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTokenSecretManager: Rolling master-key for container-tokens
2018-03-18 16:13:29,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.NMTokenSecretManagerInRM: Rolling master-key for nm-tokens
2018-03-18 16:13:29,656 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2018-03-18 16:13:29,656 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 1
2018-03-18 16:13:29,657 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2018-03-18 16:13:29,660 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2018-03-18 16:13:29,660 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2018-03-18 16:13:29,660 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMDelegationTokenSecretManager: storing master key with keyID 2
2018-03-18 16:13:29,660 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.RMStateStore: Storing RMDTMasterKey.
2018-03-18 16:13:29,662 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher: Registering class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.event.NodeLabelsStoreEventType for class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.nodelabels.CommonNodeLabelsManager$ForwardingEventHandler
2018-03-18 16:13:29,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 5000
2018-03-18 16:13:29,732 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8031
2018-03-18 16:13:30,072 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceTrackerPB to the server
2018-03-18 16:13:30,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:30,086 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8031: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:30,271 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 5000
2018-03-18 16:13:30,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8030
2018-03-18 16:13:30,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationMasterProtocolPB to the server
2018-03-18 16:13:30,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:30,286 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8030: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:30,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 5000
2018-03-18 16:13:30,386 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8032
2018-03-18 16:13:30,390 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.ApplicationClientProtocolPB to the server
2018-03-18 16:13:30,394 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:30,394 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8032: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:30,405 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager: Transitioned to active state
2018-03-18 16:13:30,686 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2018-03-18 16:13:30,705 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2018-03-18 16:13:30,711 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.resourcemanager is not defined
2018-03-18 16:13:30,733 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2018-03-18 16:13:30,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context cluster
2018-03-18 16:13:30,743 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context logs
2018-03-18 16:13:30,743 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter RMAuthenticationFilter (class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.security.http.RMAuthenticationFilter) to context static
2018-03-18 16:13:30,743 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context cluster
2018-03-18 16:13:30,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2018-03-18 16:13:30,744 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2018-03-18 16:13:30,746 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /cluster/*
2018-03-18 16:13:30,746 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: adding path spec: /ws/*
2018-03-18 16:13:31,369 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Registered webapp guice modules
2018-03-18 16:13:31,371 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 8088
2018-03-18 16:13:31,371 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2018-03-18 16:13:31,426 INFO org.mortbay.log: Extract jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.4.jar!/webapps/cluster to /tmp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8088_cluster____u0rgz3/webapp
2018-03-18 16:13:31,788 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2018-03-18 16:13:31,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Starting expired delegation token remover thread, tokenRemoverScanInterval=60 min(s)
2018-03-18 16:13:31,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.AbstractDelegationTokenSecretManager: Updating the current master key for generating delegation tokens
2018-03-18 16:13:33,623 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started HttpServer2$SelectChannelConnectorWithSafeStartup@0.0.0.0:8088
2018-03-18 16:13:33,623 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebApps: Web app cluster started at 8088
2018-03-18 16:13:33,752 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue queueCapacity: 100
2018-03-18 16:13:33,752 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 8033
2018-03-18 16:13:33,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding protocol org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPB to the server
2018-03-18 16:13:33,755 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:33,759 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 8033: starting
2018-03-18 16:13:34,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceTrackerService: NodeManager from  Master doesn't satisfy minimum allocations, Sending SHUTDOWN signal to the NodeManager.
```

Is the problem with the Slave node?

```
hadoop@Slave:/usr/local/hadoop/logs$ tail -n 50 hadoop-hadoop-datanode-Slave.log
2018-03-18 16:18:54,090 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecting to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000
2018-03-18 16:19:00,093 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:01,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:02,095 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:03,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:04,097 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:05,101 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:06,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:07,104 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-03-18 16:19:08,106 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: Slave/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
hadoop@Master:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ cat yarn-site.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
   <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Tail the resource manager logs. The node manager is running if you can see the YARN UI

Comment: @cricket_007 updated post with logs

Comment: You need to update the `/etc/hosts` files on both machines and make sure that the hostnames are on their own lines with the **external** IP address, not `127.0.0.1`. Also `NodeManager from  Master doesn't satisfy minimum allocations` means your VM doesn't have enough memory to run a resource manager with the default settings. Without seeing your yarn-site, I'm sure what those are

Comment: @cricket_007 updated IP addresses. Hmm lack of memory. ... in anycase, I added yarn-site.xml

Comment: Pretty sure you need at least 1GB of memory for each Hadoop process by default. See `minimum allocation` on that `/cluster/nodes` endpoint. Running a DataNode, ResourceManager, and NameNode on the same machine, you therefore ought to run 3GB of RAM +1GB for OS overhead. Running two VMs, you need 8GB RAM. And you need some left for your host OS outside the VM. You update Hadoop memory using these variables. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Configuring_Environment_of_Hadoop_Daemons